# How to make background service in flutter desktop?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-desktop

I'm working on a timer application when it closes it keeps running in the background. How to make a background service in flutter desktop??

I've been looking for the library on the pub dev but so far haven't been able to find it. Does anyone know how to create a background service on a flutter native desktop?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the WorkManager plugin, it lets you run process in the background even if the app is not the main focus on not in current view.

Link: https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

Comment: I think it's for android and ios, how about for desktop?